# Why do null columns behave differently with the count aggragate function?

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, we have a task to count the number of rows that have a specific null collumn.

I have the query:

```
select count(MY_COL) from My_Table where MY_COL is null;
```

this returns zero results.

Why does this return zero results and the query

```
select count(*) from My_Table where MY_COL is null;
```

return the correct results?

Comment: `count` counts only non-null values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both results *are* correct.

`select count(col_name)` counts the records where `col_name` is not null while `select count(*)` counts all records, regardless of any null values.

This is documented on [Tahiti](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions039.htm#sthref1031):

> If you specify *expr*, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr is not null. You can count either all rows, or only distinct values of *expr*.
>
> If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function returns all rows, including duplicates and nulls.
>
> COUNT never returns null.